# In a batch, how to specify a path that use a volume name instead of a drive letter?

Tags: windows, command-line, external-hard-drive, batch, path

**In a batch, is there a way to specify a path using the volume name instead of a drive letter ? (eg: something like \\RECOVERY\Docs\...)**

**Or, if not possible, is there a way to check if a specific volume name belongs to a specific drive letter (eg : if F:\ is RECOVERY do this else do that)**

Here is what i want to do : to create a batch that backup one drive to another, but since both drives (source and destination) are on removable usb drives I cannot be sure that drive letters will never change. Copying backup to working folder instead of opposite would be a catastrophic failure.

Comment: I'm not sure writing a *backup program* in *batch* is a good idea...

Comment: in fact, I will use a command line tool that will do the job for me. eg: sync "D:\documents" "E:\backup"

Comment: If your program can handle UNC paths, using `\\?\Volume{GUID}` would be a good idea, see e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc542456(v=vs.85).aspx) how to find out these paths (once).

Comment: To find out volume UNC paths, run `mountvol C: /L` in `cmd`, `C:` being the drive letter. I'll post this as an answer if you confirm it works. If it doesn't you can always mount these volumes to specific drive letters further back in the alphabet (X for source, Y for destination), and use these afterwards...

Comment: I already figured out how to find guid using HKLM\System\MountedDevices, however mountvol is faster :D. The command line tool is written in C#. I tried to give him UNC paths but it throw an exception of type System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters.

Comment: It sounds like your C# tool is pretty stupid then.  I would find it very difficult to trust any tool to perform backups that can't handle a simple UNC.

Comment: *> I'm not sure writing a backup program in batch is a good idea... – Daniel Beck*   Why not? Years ago I wrote an extensive batch file that would automate a nice, clean, proper, thorough backup using DriveImage, and it had plenty of options and switches. I also wrote an extensive backup/restore system for numerous programs and settings using two main and two or three other small batch files. (Though to be honest, a few years ago I beagn writing an even better, faster, safer backup/restore program from scratch in VC++. I can rebuild it; I have the technology.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use WMI (wmic if cmd is a must) and get label -> drive letter link from there. It's not very hard to do, but I kind of agree with a comments that batch file may not be the best solution... for so fragile backup operations. That said, here logic to get there quickly:

```
@echo off
set VAR=Source
for /f "skip=1" %%L in ('wmic logicaldisk where volumename^="SourceLabel" Get Caption') do @call :SetVar %%L
set VAR=Destination
for /f "skip=1" %%L in ('wmic logicaldisk where volumename^="DestinationLabel" Get Caption') do @call :SetVar %%L

echo Copying data from %Source% to %Destination%
goto :EOF

:SetVar
set Label=%1
if NOT [%Label%]==[] set %VAR%=%Label%
goto :EOF
```

All you need to do is replace SourceLabel with real label of source drive, same with destination label. Once you get correct references in echo command - you can put any other logic between it and "goto :EOF" directive.

Comment: great! one last question : how can i easily check if one of the volumenames is not found and print a message ?

Comment: You just need to test for var being defined, e.g. `if not defined Source (echo Source not found&&goto :EOF)
if not defined Destination (echo Destination not found&&goto :EOF)`